# How to Create Lookup Field in Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro, lookupfield

I have a table with a primary key lbxProgID.

The FK is lbxClientID that references a clients table.

zoom in of fields in question:

[image: zoom in of fields in question]

Currently when I want to add an entry to this table, I need to know the actual integer ID of the client so I can add the data.

In order to make data entry faster, is there a way to setup Sequel Pro so that when I click on the "lbxClientID" field it will show a drop-down list of the client fields in the clients table (i.e. clients.ID, clients.First, clients.Last). And when I click it enters the ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Sequel Pro support and they said it's not possible yet.

Comment: That's bad news. This is a pretty basic feature I would think - at least a much needed one.

Comment: what did you end up doing? Did you find an alternative to Sequel Pro that can do this?

Comment: How so? To do what?